# Not able to Perform multi-language search Sitecore with searchstring

Tags: solr, content-search, search-facet

Using Solr as Default search provider.

Content Search is working when website language is -en

```
example.com/en/sxa/search/results/?l=en&q=query
```

From localhost:8983(solr) Able to query the data with fields *t_en & `*t_zh` from admin panel. without any errors

But when searching data with website in language `zh` not working

```
example.com/zh-CN/sxa/search/results/?l=zh-CN&q=query
```

checked internally the website is using this sitecore method to populate results.

```
IQueryable<ContentPage> GetQuery(string query, string scope, string language, Coordinates center, string site, out string indexName)
```